# Variability in LASSO models for predicting rare events

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, lasso

I want to build a model for predicting a rare (ca 10%) event in my dataset of around 300 samples and 15 candidate predictors (of these, I know that five, when looked at individually in the whole dataset, significantly correlate with the outcome event). My approach was to split the data 75/25 into training and test sets, run 10-fold repeated cross-validation to select a model, and then test it on the holdout test set.

The problem, however, is that the models are really inconsistent and depend on the original data split. When I run the algorithm several times, two candidate predictors, which I already suspected would be the most important, are always included in the model, but it also includes a few others, and these are different each time I run the algorithm. Often, the models will include variables that have no relation to the outcome when examined individually. AUC, which I use to evaluate performance on the test set, also varies between 70-90%.

How should I approach this problem? Is the dataset too small to split, and should I rather select a model using the entire dataset, and propose validation with external data? Or, should I use a different modelling algorithm?